# Traverse a dictionary to get dependencies (using recursion perhaps?)

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, dependencies, traversal

This is the type of json files I am receiving:

```
{'n1': [5, 'number'],
 'n2': [6, 'number'],
 'm1': ['n1 x n2', 'n1 times n2'],
 'm2': ['X - m1', 'subtract n1 times n2'],
 'n3': [4, 'quarter'],
 'n4': [8, 'number'],
 'm3': ['n4 / n3', 'quarter of number n4'],
 'm4': ['m2 = m3', 'obtain m3']}
```

What I want is to get 'm4', and then traverse all the way back, such that 'm2=m3' becomes 'X - 5*6 = 8/4
I figure this might have something to do with recursion, but don't really have any experience with it.
It has to be done in Python.

The json's I receive are of varying complexities and even further dependencies, but this is the template.
Thanks!

Comment: Hooray, somebody wants you to implement [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form) in JSON 

Comment: There seems to be two problems here. On one side there is the exercise your are trying to do here, which is unclear ("such that 'm2=m3' becomes 'X - 5*6 = 8/4 "?) and probably not very useful to anyone else. On the other side there is a python nested structure access problem which can be isolated. Could you try to separate the two and ask what you want to do with an example dictionary, unrelated to your CS exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```py
table = {
    'n1': [5, 'number'],
    'n2': [6, 'number'],
    'm1': ['n1 x n2', 'n1 times n2'],
    'm2': ['X - m1', 'subtract n1 times n2'],
    'n3': [4, 'quarter'],
    'n4': [8, 'number'],
    'm3': ['n4 / n3', 'quarter of number n4'],
    'm4': ['m2 = m3', 'obtain m3']
}

string = 'm4'
while True:
    for key, (value, description) in table.items():
        if key in string:
            string = string.replace(key, str(value))
            break
    else:
        break

print(string)
```

output:

```
X - 5 x 6 = 8 / 4
```

Note that if you have circular dependency or recursive dependency, this algorithm will **never end**.